# Tomcat Memcached dependencies bundled with WAR

Tags: tomcat7, memcached

I'm currently using [memcached-tomcat-session-manager](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration#configure-tomcat) with Tomcat7 for session storage.

This is setup in the prescribed manner with the various memcached / transcoder / serializer JARs in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` and `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` with a `<Manager> ...` entry and works just fine.

A situation has arisen where I'd like to share some `static` properties of classes between my webapp and (my modified version of) memcached-session-manager. I believe with the current setup they are in separate classloaders, so sharing static resources between classes is not possible.

That led me to bundle all the dependencies with the `/WEB_INF/lib` and move the the `<Manager ...` definition to `/META-INF/context.xml`. This is not working, with Tomcat reporting:

```
portal_1     | 2018-12-21 01:26:27,291 [Portal] SEVERE {localhost-startStop-1}   Digester Begin event threw exception                                                                                               
portal_1     | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager                                                                                                                
portal_1     |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)                                                                                                                                       
portal_1     |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)                                                                                                                                            
portal_1     |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                                                                                                            
portal_1     |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)                                                                                                                
portal_1     |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1303)                                                                                                                        
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)                                                                                            
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)                                                                            
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)                                                                
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)                                                      
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)                                                                                             
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)                                                                     
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)                                                                                                 
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)                                                                                                 
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)                                                                                                                   
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)                                                                                                  
portal_1     |  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)                                                                                                
portal_1     |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1576)                                                                                                                               
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:644)                                                                                                           
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:606)                                                                                                                  
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:842)                                                                                                                           
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:399)                                                                                                                 
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)                                                                                                          
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)                                                                                                                 
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)                                                                                                                  
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:103)                                                                                                                              
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
portal_1     |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2021)
portal_1     |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
portal_1     |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
portal_1     |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
portal_1     |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
portal_1     |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm confident the dependencies are bundled in the `WAR`. After reading through Tomcat 7 documentation, its not clear to me if what I'm doing is possible - having classes defined within the WARs `context.xml` that are not in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` eg the applications classloader has not been created yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcached-session-manager (msm) jars must reside in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` because they're using tomcat internal classes (which is not possible from within the webapp). More concretely, these jar are `memcached-session-manager.jar`, `memcached-session-manager-tc7.jar` and `spymemcached.jar`.

The only msm related jars that must be put in `/WEB_INF/lib` are serialization related jars such as `msm-kryo-serializer` (usually defined as dependencies in your maven/gradle/xyz build), because they must be able to access application specific classes.

See also the related [msm documentation](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration#configure-tomcat).

Regarding your goal to share information between msm and your application: Because msm jars must reside in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, conceptually it's not possible to statically "link" application code with msm code (except msm serializer related code). This is only possible with an additional indirection: the definition of some interface inside msm, where the application provides an implementation and which msm then loads via reflection. This is how serializers are hooked into msm, see [the TranscoderFactory interface](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/javakaffee/web/msm/TranscoderFactory.java) (loaded from `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`) and the [KryoTranscoderFactory implementation](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/blob/master/kryo-serializer/src/main/java/de/javakaffee/web/msm/serializer/kryo/KryoTranscoderFactory.java) (loaded from `/WEB_INF/lib`).